# A pentagon that can measure the first 7 integer distances

Tags: mathematics, geometry, construction

A pentagon can be used to measure 10 distances - one distance between each pair of its 5 vertices. Can you find a pentagon that can measure every integer distance from 1 to 7, inclusive?

Comment: Can't you use it to measure a distance using more than one pair of vertices? Like if the neighbouring edges are `1` and `2` then you can roll the pentagon on its side and measure `3`?

Comment: Well if you have edge 1 then you can measure any integer distance...

Comment: Seeing just the title, I guessed that this was one of @DmitryKamenetsky's puzzles ;)

Comment: @Oliphaunt wow how did you do that?

Comment: For those interested, a hexagon can measure the first 9 distances. See if you can find it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer is

> yes.
>
>  [image: pentagon]

This can be proven by

> computing the length of the diagonal determined by the 2-3-4 and 4-5-6 triangles as $$\sqrt{\frac{983+45\sqrt{105}}{32}}\approx6.71778$$ using the [Cayley-Menger determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Menger_determinant), which is strictly between 6 and 8, thereby satisfying the triangle inequality for the sides of lengths 1 and 7.

Comment: Very nice work! Do you think it's possible to add distance 8?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky No because the segment of length 1 together with the 3 vertices not on that segment form 3 triangles with 3 distinct pairs of segments. Each pair can have at most 1 integral length by the triangle inequality (unless we permit degenerate pentagons), so we can have at most 10 - 3 = 7 integral lengths.

Comment: Here's a degenerate pentagon that can count up to 9: https://i.stack.imgur.com/slrz7.png

Comment: The proof isn't quite convincing though: having three vertices on the same line doesn't necessarily make a pentagon degenerate.

Comment: @Bass You're right, that only holds for convex pentagons.

Answer (score 28):

A possibly more elegant solution for 1..7 if we don't insist on a convex pentagon.

> [image]
>
>  Note: some angles appear to be right angles but none are.

Comment: That's very nice

Comment: Sriram Sathyamoorthy comments: There are quite a few answers if we are not constrained by a convex pentagon.

Comment: That is true.  For instance the figure above can be seen as a quadrilateral split along the diagonals, with one sector removed.  Any other sector could be removed instead.  I chose this one for purely esthetic reasons.

Answer (score 18):

> I first drew the lines 7, 6 and 5, then connected the ends with 4 and 3, then calculated the length of the top line, which turned out to be 2.583. $1 + 2 > 2.583$, so 1 and 2 can fit on top.

> [image: enter link description here]